# How to keep my Laravel docker app data when using docker-compose down and up?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, volumes

I am trying to use docker to my my laravel project.
I am using bitnami's laravel image https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/laravel
Everything works perfectly, the 3 containers are raised and they are connected to each other, but I would like that when doing "docker-compose down" and later "docker-compose up -d" the data would not be lost and my app works
For this I have created several volumes

```
  myapp:
    container_name: wallamotop
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:10
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USERNAME=daniel
      - DB_DATABASE=wallamotop
    volumes:
      - './app:/opt/bitnami/laravel' 
      - './app/entrypoint.sh:/opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel/entrypoint.sh'    
      - './app/storage/app/public/imagenes:/opt/bitnami/laravel/storage/app/public/imagenes' 
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - wallamotop_network
```

In entrypoint.sh I run the commands "php artisan migrate" "php artisan db:seed" and "php artisan storage:link", inside the conditional. The script works fine, the problem is the volume for the storage folder and the images, when I upload images to my app they are showed to me, the problem is when I do "docker-compose down" and later doing "docker-compose up -d" and the images are deleted, as if the volume did not store the data.
Images are stored in: storage/app/pubic/images

entrypoint.sh archive:

```
#!/bin/bash

# shellcheck disable=SC1091

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail
# set -o xtrace # Uncomment this line for debugging purposes

# Load libraries
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/libbitnami.sh
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/liblog.sh
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/libos.sh

# Load Laravel environment
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel-env.sh

print_welcome_page

if [[ "$*" = *"/opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel/run.sh"* ]]; then
    info "** Running Laravel setup **"
    /opt/bitnami/scripts/php/setup.sh
    /opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel/setup.sh
    /post-init.sh

    php artisan storage:link

    if ! docker volume inspect mariadb_data >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        info "MariaDB volume not found. Running migrations and seeders..."
        php artisan migrate --no-interaction
        php artisan db:seed --no-interaction
    else
        info "MariaDB volume found. Skipping migration and seeding..."
    fi

    info "** Laravel setup finished! **"
fi


echo ""
exec "$@"
```

docker-compose.yml archive:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.6
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=daniel
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=wallamotop
    volumes:
      - mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb/data    

    networks:
      - wallamotop_network

  myapp:
    container_name: wallamotop
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:10
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USERNAME=daniel
      - DB_DATABASE=wallamotop
    volumes:
      - './app:/opt/bitnami/laravel' 
      - './app/entrypoint.sh:/opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel/entrypoint.sh'    
      - './app/storage/app/public/imagenes:/opt/bitnami/laravel/storage/app/public/imagenes' 
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - wallamotop_network

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mariadb:db
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      - MYSQL_USER=daniel
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
    networks:
      - wallamotop_network

volumes:
  mariadb_data:

networks:
  wallamotop_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Thanks for your time. I hope I can solve the problem with your help :)